# HTML viewport tag sometimes ignored in mobile Chrome on first visit

Tags: html, mobile, viewport, meta-tags

For my adaptive website, I use the viewport meta tag to force the device to show the page in its "preferred" screen resolution (not actual device resolution, but the "smallest" resolution with initial scale 1.0).

*Viewport meta tag:*

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

This seems to work well on all devices, but, on mobile Chrome and sometimes on IOS devices, first/uncached visit does not detect the device's "preferred" resolution right away, but *communicates* the actual screen resolution.

*Setup to reproduce the error (in head section of the page):*

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(window.innerWidth);
</script>
```

First/uncached visit will show "980" for my Nexus 5, second visit/refresh will show the desired "360".

Does anybody know a way to force the window to use initial scale, without javascript timeout or window onload workarounds?

---

**Edited:** *Checking window.innerWidth after window.onload returns the desired "preferred" width. That is my workaround for now...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: **window.innerWidth** is somehow delayed and returns the value of the *not-viewport-resized* document width in an *early* stage of the page load. **document.documentElement.clientWidth** seems to have no problems when calculating window width in *early* page load stage.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript">
    // So use this to calculate device width rules before window.onload
    alert(document.documentElement.clientWidth);
</script>
```

*Note: You are able to use window.innerWidth later on, e.g. after window.onload.*